# how to recover the database of MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have ran the below command but after run the command my database has gone.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO myuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
```

what is wrong with this command..?

I had put my database name at the place of mydb,  username at the place of myuser and password at the place of mypasswd.

Can any one please tell me how can i **get my database back.**  Thanks

Comment: That's probably not what messed up your database.
You probably have to update the MySQL connection info in the configuration files of your site, to match the username and password you used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connect to your database localy. 
Something like

```
mysql -u myuser -pmypasswd
```

If you can't do that - try create new user or drop old with init script.
Just create file with strings

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'example'@'%' identified by 'strongpassword';
drop user 'myuser'@'localhost';
flush privileges;
```

After that you can start you mysql server with option "--init-file=path_to_file"